# Point was not declared

Tags: c++

here is the error:
I do not know why this strange error! 'Point' & 'Vector' are "Droite3D" attribute of class!
help please

```
    ******************************* Droite3D.h**************************



#ifndef DROITE3D_H
#define DROITE3D_H
#include<iostream>
#include<Point3D.h>
#include<Vecteur3D.h>``

class Droite3D
{
    Point3D Point;
    Vecteur3D Vecteur;

    public:

    Droite3D(Point3D p, Vecteur3D v){
        Point=p;
        Vecteur=v;
    }

    void afficher();
    void afficher ( ostream & out) const;
};
```

************************* Droite3D.cpp******************************

```
#include "Droite3D.h"
#include<iostream>

ostream & operator<< (ostream & out, const Droite3D &D)
{
    D.afficher (out);
    return out;
}
}

void afficher ( ostream & out) const{
    cout <<"\nc'est la droite definie par le point "<<Point<<" et le vecteur "<<Vecteur;
```

Comment: I doubt you got such a gramatically incorrect error message. Please copy the exact error, and specify what line it was on.

Comment: Line 10 : error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"\012c\'est la droite definie par le point ")) << ((Droite3D*)this)->Droite3D::Point'|

Answer (score 1):

`afficher` is  member of `Droite3D`, so you need to place its definition in that scope:

```
void Droite3D::afficher ( ostream & out) const
{//  ^^^^^^^^^^
  out <<"\nc'est la droite definie par le point "
       <<Point<<" et le vecteur "<<Vecteur;
}
```

Otherwise you are defining a non-member `afficher`, which obviously doesn't know anything about `Point` or `Vecteur`.

Note that you also want to stream to `out`, not `cout`.

Comment: thank you I corrected it but I got this error after
no match for 'operator <<' in 'std :: operator <<< std :: char_traits <char>> .....

Comment: @user3162727 You also need to overload `std::ostream& operator<<` for `Point` and `Vecteur`.

Comment: @user3162727 you should probably post another question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and the complete compiler error message.

Answer (score 1):

Please use scope resolution operator `::` while defining method `afficher` as its using the variables of class `Droite3D` so you need to mention its scope.

Comment: thank you I corrected it but I got this error after
no match for 'operator <<' in 'std :: operator <<< std :: char_traits <char>> .....

Comment: please use out parameter your passing to that method

Comment: Line 10 : error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"\012c\'est la droite definie par le point ")) << ((Droite3D*)this)->Droite3D::Point'|